# Javascript to call a javascript from another website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

There are 2 websites. Mine and a clients. The client needs to be able to invoke a JS that calls my JS which returns something back to the client. When i get the call from the client i need to verify their account info as well. So i've been asked to create the API for these 2 functions and i'm pretty new to web development. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting an AJAX style of call to a php web-service or page. Have a look at jQuery.ajax(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I need to build an interface for the client to access data from my server, can i do this without AJAX? Right now we've all decided on using cakePHP all around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're asking quite a bit there (although very little in detail).

You want to look into a REST API which handles at minimum GET and POST. It should return JSON data.

Then you can use AJAX calls from the client's site to your API (not sure why you think you have to have JS on your site, that requirement isn't clear).

As mentioned, calling JS across sites presents security risks, so you have to use JSONP.

You'll get better answers from this site when you ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

You could load JS code from both sites, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="site1-code.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site2.com/othercode.js" />
```

However, it sounds more like you'd want a cross-domain AJAX call, which means you'd be using a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) service.

Comment: Cross site scripting may stop this from working, depending upon your browser.

Comment: Requesting script files from other hosts does not violate cross site scripting restrictions.  Example: Google hosts jQuery for general use; that would not be possible.